# How to use a $_. variable in a herestring?

Tags: powershell, variables, herestring

I can't seem to figure out how to use a variable in a herestring, and for the variable to be expanded at a later time in a piped command.  I have experimented with single `'` and double `"` quotes, and escape `` ` `` characters.

I am trying to use the herestring for a list (e.g. like an array) of Exchange groups, and a corresponding list of conditions to apply to those groups.  Here is a simplified example which fails to use the `$Conditions` variable correctly (it does not expand the `$_.customattribute2` variable):

```
# List of groups and conditions (tab delimitered)
$records = @"
Group1  {$_.customattribute2 -Like '*Sales*'}
Group2  {$_.customattribute2 -Like '*Marketing*' -OR $_.customattribute2 -Eq 'CEO'}
"@

# Loop through each line in $records and find mailboxes that match $conditions
foreach ($record in $records -split "`n") {
    ($DGroup,$Conditions) = $record -split "`t"

    $MailboxList = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
    $MailboxList | where $Conditions
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TessellatingHeckler's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47108771/3439404) is right. However, if you insist on herestring, it's possible as well. See the following example (created merely for demonstration):

```
$records=@'
Group1  {$_.Extension -Like "*x*" -and $_.Name -Like "m*"}
Group2  {$_.Extension -Like "*p*" -and $_.Name -Like "t*"}
'@
foreach ($record in $records -split "`n") {
    ($DGroup,$Conditions) = $record -split "`t"
    "`r`n{0}={1}" -f $DGroup,$Conditions
    (Get-ChildItem | 
        Where-Object { . (Invoke-Expression $Conditions) }).Name
}
```

**Output**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\47108347.ps1

Group1={$_.Extension -Like "*x*" -and $_.Name -Like "m*"}
myfiles.txt

Group2={$_.Extension -Like "*p*" -and $_.Name -Like "t*"}
Tabulka stupnic.pdf
ttc.ps1

PS D:\PShell>
```

**Caution**: some text/code editors could convert tabulators to space sequences!

Comment: Thanks, it was `Invoke-Expression` that I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

No, no that's not going to work. The whole good bit about PowerShell is not having to make everything a string and then drag it to the moon and back trying to get the important stuff back out of the string. `{$_.x -eq "y"}` is a scriptblock. It's a thing by itself, you don't need to put it in a string.

```
#Array of arrays. Pairs of groups and conditions
[Array]$records = @(

  ('Group1', {$_.customattribute2 -Like '*Sales*'}),
  ('Group2', {$_.customattribute2 -Like '*Marketing*' -OR $_.customattribute2 -Eq 'CEO'})

)

#Loop through each line in $records and find mailboxes that match $conditions
foreach ($pair in $records) {

        $DGroup, $Condition = $pair

        $MailboxList = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
        $MailboxList | where $Condition
}
```

Comment: I'd argue that a hashtable would be a more suitable data structure than an array here.

Comment: I agree with @AnsgarWiechers, hashtables of group names and conditions would fit more nicely for real world use, and I started writing it as a Hashtable version - but decided that the extra property names and using `{}` unrelated to scriptblocks might obscure the point, so I made it close to the original 'shape' of a list of separated pairs instead.

Comment: Whilst this probably the better powershell way of doing it, @JosefZ answered my specific question.